# Chrome suddenly only works in incognito mode, how to force logout of user account?

Tags: google-chrome

As of today, for some reason Chrome has stopped loading pages unless I'm in incognito mode, it will just hang and never load a page otherwise. So it seems to be a problem when logged into my user account. But I can't logout because it's trying to load a logout page which it can't complete.

Someone had a [similar issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/dvmr6/chrome_stopped_working_mysteriously/) and the following was suggested:

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome

mv Local\ State old.Local\ State
```

However that doesn't log me out, it still shows me as logged in and the issue persists.I also tried uninstalling and re-installing chrome but it still has me logged in.

Comment: You can try to move the whole `~/.config/google-chrome` directory. However, before you do this, exit Chrome and kill any `chrome` processes that seem to hang..

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any idea what files / directories I can move from the old config directory to the new one to restore things like bookmarks etc.?